# free() não funciona em código de Pilha dinâmica

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, alocação, stack

A pilha dinâmica funciona normalmente, mas quando tento utilizar o método free() para desalocar a memória dos elementos removidos e reinicializar a estrutura, o compilador não retorna o esperado. Na realidade, não aparece nada, nenhum erro, mas não funciona. O código só passa a funcionar normalmente depois de comentar a função free().

Já procurei onde estaria o possível erro, mas não encontrei. Tenho quase certeza que é falha na estrutura do código. Porém, como eu disse acima, aparentemente funciona exceto quando tento desalocar memória e não sei onde está o erro.

**Funções onde *aparentemente* acontece o problema (pop e restartStack):**

```
int pop (STACK *stack) {

    if (stack->top != NULL) {
        ELEMENT *aux = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        free(aux);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

```
void restartStack (STACK *stack) {
    ELEMENT *position = stack->top;

    while (position != NULL) {
        ELEMENT *remove = position;
        position = position->next;
        free(remove);
    }

    stack->top = NULL;

}
```

**A estrutura como um todo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define TRUE 0
#define FALSE 1
#define DEBUG
#undef DEBUG
typedef int TYPEKEY;


typedef struct {
    TYPEKEY key;
    struct ELEMENT* next;
} ELEMENT;

typedef struct {
    ELEMENT *top;
} STACK;

void startStack (STACK *stack) {
    stack->top = NULL;
}

int stackLenght (STACK *stack) {
    ELEMENT *element = stack->top;
    int lenght = 0;

    while (element != NULL) {
        element = element->next;
        lenght++;
    }

    return lenght;
}

int isEmpty (STACK *stack) {
    return stack->top == NULL ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

void showElements (STACK *stack) {
    ELEMENT *element = stack->top;

    while (element != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", element->key);
        element = element->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void push (STACK *stack, ELEMENT *elementToInsert) {

    /* Aloca memória */
    ELEMENT *aux = (ELEMENT*) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    /* Guarda o antigo topo */
    aux = stack->top;

    /* O novo elemento é o topo*/
    stack->top = elementToInsert;

    /* O antigo topo é o next */
    elementToInsert->next = aux;

}

int pop (STACK *stack) {

    if (stack->top != NULL) {
        ELEMENT *aux = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;
        free(aux);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

ELEMENT* topStack (STACK *stack) {
    return stack->top != NULL ? stack->top : NULL;
}

void restartStack (STACK *stack) {
    ELEMENT *position = stack->top;

    while (position != NULL) {
        ELEMENT *remove = position;
        position = position->next;
        free(remove);
    }

    stack->top = NULL;

}
```

**main:**

```
int main () {
        ELEMENT ELEMENT, ELEMENT2, ELEMENT3;

        STACK stack;

        ELEMENT.key = 5;
        ELEMENT2.key = 7;
        ELEMENT3.key = 2;

        startStack(&stack);
        push(&stack, &ELEMENT);
        push(&stack, &ELEMENT2);
        push(&stack, &ELEMENT3);
        //pop(&stack); - ERRO, COMPILADOR FICAR EM LOOPING OU RETORNA UM EXIT CODE != 0
        //restartStack(&stack); - ERRO, COMPILADOR FICAR EM LOOPING OU RETORNA UM EXIT CODE != 0

        printf("%d\n", stackLenght(&stack));

        showElements(&stack);
}
```

Comment: Use nomes mais significativos. Que é essa meiga `struct aux`? Porque não deixou uma versão de `main()` com um teste?

Comment: Opa. Perdão, eu esqueci de declarar aux em cima da struct. Eu editei. No caso seria uma referência da própria struct. Coloquei um exemplo do main também.

Comment: Você alocou memória na stack e está tentando limpar ela.

Comment: Perdão, não entendi a sua resposta

Comment: a memória foi alocada normalmente, no heap por um push anterior... estava errado o sizeof() antes, mas o autor corrigiu

Comment: não é o compilador que fica em "looping". É o seu programa que cancela. O compilador só gera o programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja bem, você está deixando com que o compilador faça a alocação, e depois, tenta liberar essa memória(se não me engano, o comportamento disso é indefinido, o que pode dar muitas dores de cabeça).

```c
int pop (STACK *stack) {

    if (stack->top != NULL) {
        ELEMENT *aux = stack->top;
        stack->top = stack->top->next;

        // irá funcionar porque tenho certeza que aloquei memória na heap
        free(aux);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

```c
/**
* Apenas espero a chave, a memória irei alocar internamente
 sendo assim, tenho controle de quando devo desalocar
*/ 
void push (STACK *stack, int key) {

    // aloca memória no heap
    ELEMENT *element = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    element->key = key;
    element->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = element;
}
```

```c
int main () {

        STACK stack;

        startStack(&stack);
        push(&stack, 5);
        push(&stack, 10);
        push(&stack, 15);
        
        printf("%d\n", stackLenght(&stack));

        showElements(&stack);
        pop(&stack);
        showElements(&stack);
        push(&stack, 900);
        showElements(&stack);
}
```

Ao compilar com o `gcc` você verá alguns warnings do compilador como "assignment from incompatible pointer type" isso porque você definiu a struct como `ELEMENT` e não `struct ELEMENT` e dentro da própria struct ELEMENT, você está utilizando `struct ELEMENT`.

Para corrigir:

```c
typedef struct ELEMENT {
    TYPEKEY key;
    struct ELEMENT *next;
} ELEMENT;
```

Comment: @Staniack corrige um erro de digitação meu na alocacação de memória, eu estava utilizando alocacando memória para um ponteiro, o que daŕa problema no futuro. Também atualizei a resposta por causa de um aviso do compilador(que nao daria problema, mas é chato)

Comment: Eu corrigi. Esqueci-me de agradecê-lo. Erro bobo meu, mas que compromete todo o funcionamento. Você diz (ELEMENT*) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT))? Eu eventualmente faço isso, mas qual seria o problema em fazê-lo?

Comment: O cast não é necessário, mas se você olhar as minhas edições, verá que eu tinha `malloc(sizeof(element));` Só que *element* era um ponteiro, sendo assim, estava alocando apenas 8 bytes(tamanho de um ponteiro em máquinas 64 bits)

Answer (score 1):

Estruturas como essa pilha são chamadas de containers em C++ ou de coleções em java, e na literatura aparecem como ADT, estruturas abstratas de dados. E você tem que aproximar seu programa disso, do lado abstrato. Vou mostrar um exemplo abaixo.

No geral o container é um conjunto `S` possivelmente vazio de registros `X`, e cada registro tem um conteúdo que em geral contém uma chave `k`. E assim você escreve todas as funções em termos de ponteiros para nós e os nós em geral tem apenas um ponteiro para o registro, que por sua vez contem a chave.

Em programas para estudo muitas vezes o registro é a própria chave só, como uma letrinha ou no seu caso um simples `int`:

```
typedef int TYPEKEY;
```

Você não usou um ponteiro mas sim uma chave alocada DENTRO do registro.

Na primeira versão você estava alocando o tamanho errado em `push()`. Agora parece certo. Mas entenda que ao inserir algo na pilha ou retornar você deve copiar os dados para dentro da pilha e ao retirar você deve retornar uma cópia deles.

O problema é que o usuário da pilha pode passar várias vezes o mesmo registro, ou passar uma chave para `key` a partir de um ponteiro que veio de sei lá onde. Se você colocar isso na pilha um `pop()` posterior vai cancelar seu programa. Ou um `restart()` ou `delete()`. Não podem haver ponteiros soltos pelo programa se referindo a áreas dentro da pilha. E vice-versa.

Um outro ponto, e que pode ver em uma resposta logo acima, é que o acesso aos elementos da pilha é feito em termos da chave, não em termos do nó em si: a estrutura do nó é uma coisa interna à pilha.

No seu caso, você faz um `push()` de um `TYPEKEY`, não de um `ELEMENT`. E `top()` retorna um ponteiro para `key`, não para um nó.

#### EXEMPLO

alterei um pouco seu programa e pode comparar as funções. Antes de tudo as estruturas

```
typedef int Key;

typedef struct aux_
{
    Key             key;
    struct aux_*    next;

}   Element;

typedef struct
{
    Element*    top;
    unsigned    size;

}   Stack;
```

Usei a convenção comum de reservar nomes com a primeira letra em maiúscula para os `typedef` e, apesar de não ser o comum, mantive no node a chave e não o ponteiro para ela, que é o mais comum. `size` é uma questão prática: é bom ter um contador atualizado. é normal implementar a pilha usando um **vetor** alocado dinamicamente e aí teria também o valor da capacidade, e tudo ficaria muito mais rápido, usando ponteiros como índices e não `Element*`

#### As funções

```
int         empty (Stack*);
int         pop   (Stack*);
int         push  (Key*,Stack*);
int         size  (Stack*);
Key*        top   (Stack*);
```

Esses são o nomes como usados em C++, por exemplo. Mas note que

- não há `void`: sempre retorna um status, negativo para erro, 0 para sucesso, como é comum em C.
- `push()` recebe um ponteiro para `Key` e não para `Element`: `Element` é algo interno
- `top()` retorna um ponteiro para a chave, mas um ponteiro para uma **cópia** do registro, e é importante entender isso: você não sabe o que o usuário vai fazer com a chave, e assim tem que retornar uma cópia, e o usuário da API é responsável --- *owner* --- pelo ponteiro e deve liberar a memória quando não for usar mais o registro. Várias chamadas a `top()` seguidas retornam ponteiros para cópias do mesmo registro e se o usuário da API liberar um não vai zoar o outro. É importante entender isso. Veja no programa exemplo.

#### As outras funções

```
Stack*      deleteStack  (Stack*);
int         restartStack (Stack*); // empties
int         showStack    (Stack*,const char*); // list all
Stack*      startStack   (unsigned); // return new
```

`deleteStack()` retorna NULL. Apenas para poder ser usado numa expressão e invalidar o próprio ponteiro da pilha no programa. Veja no exemplo.

- `restartStack()` não precisa mas pode e foi aqui escrita em termos de `pop()` para evitar repetição de código
- `showStack()` é uma função de teste. Não existe numa pilha normal e não faz sentido: numa pilha só se vê um elemento por vez. Acrescentei um parâmetro, um `const char*`, para mostrar um título opcional, porque é uma "mão na roda" nos testes.

#### O programa de exemplo

O programa cria uma pilha com um certo número de registros, mostra, apaga a metade deles e lista o resto. Depois testa o `restart()`, o `delete()` e encerra. Não testei muito mas pode servir.

Eis o código:

```
int main(void)
{
    const int tamanho = 10;
    Stack* nova = startStack(tamanho);
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha vazia ainda...");
    printf("Vai inserir 1..10\n");
    for( int i = 1; i<=tamanho; i+=1) push(&i,nova);
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha agora");
    printf("Tenta remover metade dos elementos\n");
    Key* p = NULL;
    int n = nova->size/2;
    for ( int i = 0; i<n; i+= 1)
    {
        printf("Vai remover '%d'\n", *(p = top(nova)));
        free(p); // nao vai usar mais
        pop(nova);
    };  // for()
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha agora:");
    printf("Usando restart() na pilha\n");
    restartStack(nova);
    showStack(nova,"teste: depois do restart()");
    printf("Apagando a pilha\n");
    nova = deleteStack(nova);
    printf("Apagando a pilha\n");
    showStack(nova,"vazia?");
    showStack(nova,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

#### A saída do exemplo

```
toninho@DSK-2009:~/projects/triangle$ ./build/stan
teste: pilha vazia ainda...
Pilha com 0 elementos


Vai inserir 1..10
teste: pilha agora
Pilha com 10 elementos
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

Tenta remover metade dos elementos
Vai remover '10'
Vai remover '9'
Vai remover '8'
Vai remover '7'
Vai remover '6'
teste: pilha agora:
Pilha com 5 elementos
5 4 3 2 1 

Usando restart() na pilha
teste: depois do restart()
Pilha com 0 elementos


Apagando a pilha
Apagando a pilha
Pilha nao construida!
Pilha nao construida!
```

#### push()

```
int         push (Key* k, Stack* s)
{
    // cria um elemento e coloca na pilha.
    // retorna o tamanho se ok, ou algo negativo
    if ( s == NULL ) return -1;
    if ( k == NULL ) return -2;
    Element* el = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if ( el == NULL ) return -3;
    el->key = *k; // shallow copy here!!
    el->next = s->top; // new at the TOP
    s->top = el;
    s->size += 1;
    return s->size;
}
```

Apenas note que é criado um elemento e a chave é copiada para dentro. Assim se o usuário da API liberar o ponteiro depois não vai destruir a pilha...

#### restart()

```
int         restartStack(Stack* s)
{
    if ( s == NULL ) return -1;
    while ( s->size > 0 ) pop(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja que é mais simples escrever restart() a partir de pop(), além de ser um lugar a menos para testar :)

#### O programa todo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef int Key;

typedef struct aux_
{
    Key             key;
    struct aux_*    next;

}   Element;

typedef struct
{
    Element*    top;
    unsigned    size;

}   Stack;
// classic
int         empty (Stack*);
int         pop   (Stack*);
int         push  (Key*,Stack*);
int         size  (Stack*);
Key*        top   (Stack*); 
// support
Stack*      deleteStack  (Stack*);
int         restartStack (Stack*); // empties
int         showStack    (Stack*,const char*); // list all
Stack*      startStack   (unsigned); // return new

int main(void)
{
    const int tamanho = 10;
    Stack* nova = startStack(tamanho);
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha vazia ainda...");
    printf("Vai inserir 1..10\n");
    for( int i = 1; i<=tamanho; i+=1) push(&i,nova);
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha agora");
    printf("Tenta remover metade dos elementos\n");
    Key* p = NULL;
    int n = nova->size/2;
    for ( int i = 0; i<n; i+= 1)
    {
        printf("Vai remover '%d'\n", *(p = top(nova)));
        free(p); // nao vai usar mais
        pop(nova);
    };  // for()
    showStack(nova,"teste: pilha agora:");
    printf("Usando restart() na pilha\n");
    restartStack(nova);
    showStack(nova,"teste: depois do restart()");
    printf("Apagando a pilha\n");
    nova = deleteStack(nova);
    printf("Apagando a pilha\n");
    showStack(nova,"vazia?");
    showStack(nova,NULL);
    return 0;
}

int         empty (Stack* S)
{
    return S->size == 0;
}

int         pop (Stack* S)
{
    if ( S == NULL ) return -1;
    if ( empty(S) )  return -2;
    Element* to_delete = S->top;
    S->top = S->top->next;
    S->size -= 1;
    free(to_delete);
    return S->size;
}

int         push (Key* k, Stack* s)
{
    // cria um elemento e coloca na pilha.
    // retorna o tamanho se ok, ou algo negativo
    if ( s == NULL ) return -1;
    if ( k == NULL ) return -2;
    Element* el = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if ( el == NULL ) return -3;
    el->key = *k; // shallow copy here!!
    el->next = s->top; // new at the TOP
    s->top = el;
    s->size += 1;
    return s->size;
}

int         size(Stack* s)
{
    if ( s == NULL ) return -1;
    return s->size;
}

Key*        top(Stack* s)
{
    if ( s == NULL ) return NULL;
    Key* k = (Key*) malloc(sizeof(k));
    *k = s->top->key;
    return k;
}

Stack*      deleteStack(Stack* s)
{
    if ( s == NULL ) return NULL;
    while ( s->size > 0 ) pop(s);
    return NULL;
}

int         restartStack(Stack* s)
{
    if ( s == NULL ) return -1;
    while ( s->size > 0 ) pop(s);
    return 0;
}


int         showStack (Stack* s, const char* msg)
{   
    // prints stack nodes along with optional message
    if ( s == NULL )
    {
        printf("Pilha nao construida!\n");
        return -1;
    };
    if ( msg != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n", msg);
    }
    printf("Pilha com %d elementos\n", s->size);
    Element* p = s->top;
    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", p->key );
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return s->size;
}

Stack*      startStack (unsigned sz)
{
    const unsigned dflt = 1000;  // default size
    Stack*      stack = (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if ( stack == NULL ) return NULL;
    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->size = 0;
    return stack;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, suas dicas valerão ouro! Essa parte do retorno de ponteiros foi ingenuidade da minha parte, isso altera completamente a estrutura. Bom, agora eu sei que não posso fazer isso.

Comment: :) Atente para essa distinção sempre entre container e conteúdo. Todas ADT são iguais, e os sistemas em si são assim também. C foi escrita exatamente para escrever esse tipo de solução, essa construção tipo _factory_ como em `Stack* pilha = startStack(500)`. E esse lance de _owning pointer_  de modo que você não aceita nada de fora e só retorna cópias do que tem dentro é outra coisa para manter um olho em cima.